# page document mode

Tags: asp.net, html, css, master-pages

I've an aspx page that extends a master page. I want to change aspx page's document mode. I'd like to put this line to aspx page. But It doesn't allow. I don't want to put this code to master page's head want only change the page's document mode. Can somebody help me?

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a placeholder in your masterpage:

```
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="plhHead" runat="server"/>
</head>
```

If your `<html/>` tag has no `runat="server"`, you need to apply it to the `<head/>` tag like KPL did. 
And then fill it in the client page like you do with your main content placeholder:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="plhHead" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place a ContentPlaceHolder in the head section of your Master Page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Now from your `.aspx` page, you can add custom content in the head section:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to placing a `ContentPlaceHolder` in the Master page, you can do this:

```
// Programmatically add a <meta> element to the Header
HtmlMeta keywords = new HtmlMeta();
keywords.Name = "X-UA-Compatible";
keywords.Content = "IE=9";

Page.Header.Controls.Add(keywords);
```